# Google App Script accessing third level JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, rest, google-apps-script, alpha-vantage

When I tried calling `hello()` on my Google Sheets, it return

> Error TypeError: Cannot read property '5. Exchange Rate' of undefined (line 50).

Trigger for the Apps Script is also set up

| Criteria | set |
| --- | --- |
| Choose which function to run | hello |
| Which runs at deployment | head |
| Select event source | From spreadsheet |
| Select event type | On Open |
| Failure notification settings | Notify me Daily |

**JSON OBJECT**

```
{
    "Realtime Currency Exchange Rate": {
        "1. From_Currency Code": "USD",
        "2. From_Currency Name": "United States Dollar",
        "3. To_Currency Code": "SGD",
        "4. To_Currency Name": "Singapore Dollar",
        "5. Exchange Rate": "1.32783000",
        "6. Last Refreshed": "2021-02-26 01:28:59",
        "7. Time Zone": "UTC",
        "8. Bid Price": "1.32783000",
        "9. Ask Price": "1.32783000"
    }
}
```

**Google App Script function**

```
function hello(){
  var usdCurrency = "USD";
  var AV_API_Key = "KEYS";
  var sgdCurrency = "SGD"
  var url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE&from_currency=" + usdCurrency + "&to_currency=" + sgdCurrency  + "&apikey=" + AV_API_Key;

  var response =  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var result =  JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var currencyPrice = result["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"]["5. Exchange Rate"];
  
  Logger.log(currencyPrice); // 1.32794000
  Logger.log(typeof(currencyPrice)); // String
  return currencyPrice;
  
}
```

### Update

I set a predefined variable named `jsonObj`, it is able get the item in the object and place it in the google sheets.

```
function initTesting(){
  var jsonObj = {
    "Realtime Currency Exchange Rate": {
        "1. From_Currency Code": "USD",
        "2. From_Currency Name": "United States Dollar",
        "3. To_Currency Code": "SGD",
        "4. To_Currency Name": "Singapore Dollar",
        "5. Exchange Rate": "1.32783000",
        "6. Last Refreshed": "2021-02-26 01:28:59",
        "7. Time Zone": "UTC",
        "8. Bid Price": "1.32783000",
        "9. Ask Price": "1.32783000"
    }
};
var getPrice = jsonObj["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"]["5. Exchange Rate"];
return getPrice;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it is a bug or something but I have work around a solution.

```
function hello(){
  var usdCurrency = "USD";
  var AV_API_Key = "KEYS";
  var sgdCurrency = "SGD"
  var url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE&from_currency=" + usdCurrency + "&to_currency=" + sgdCurrency  + "&apikey=" + AV_API_Key;

  var response =  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var result =  JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var currencyPrice = result["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"]["5. Exchange Rate"];
```

Even though when I initially logged  `Logger.log(typeof(currencyPrice));` it showed String on the log. But once I use a `String()` in the code below, it is able to reflect on the google sheets.

```
  Logger.log(currencyPrice); // 1.32794000
  Logger.log(typeof(currencyPrice)); // String
  // uses  String() on the currency price
  stringCurrencyPrice = String(currencyPrice)
  return stringcurrencyPrice;
  
}

}
```